# Creating a table with autoincrement column: '' is not a valid name

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I use UCanAccess (4.0.2) to create a new file with a single table like this:

```
// Create a database + connect
DatabaseBuilder.create(FileFormat.V2010, new File(path));
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");     
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + path + ";singleconnection=true" ,"", ""); 

// Create table     
String sql = "CREATE TABLE Test (id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, value CHAR(1) NOT NULL)";
conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
```

The code works but the resulting table seems to be incomplete/flawed. Trying to copy it in Access results in an error:

> '' is not a valid name...

Doesn't seem to be a big problem as saving the table from the design view solves it.

Any idea why that happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: I have been able to reproduce your issue with the latest UCanAccess development code. The team will investigate and I'll post an answer with any news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to a confirmed issue with Jackcess versions 2.1.8 and older. A [fix](https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/bugs/144/) has been applied to Jackcess that will be included in the next release (tentatively 2.1.9). Once a UCanAccess update is released that includes the Jackcess fix then the problem should go away.