# Not null constraint not enforced by ms access after creating table with UCanAccess

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

This is a follow-up to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405841/creating-a-table-with-autoincrement-column-is-not-a-valid-name/46626283#46626283) question. The error is a bit different with the new UCanAccess version now.

I create a database file with a table containing a NOT-NULL column using the latest UCanAccess (4.0.3, including Jackcess 2.1.9) like this

```
    // Create a database + connect
    DatabaseBuilder.create(FileFormat.V2010, new File(path));
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");     
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + path + ";singleconnection=true" ,"", ""); 
    
    // Create table     
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE Test (id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, value CHAR(1) NOT NULL)";
    conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
```

Trying to insert values works fine via UCanAccess, NULL is rejected for the column 'value' by UCanAccess as expected.
However, when I use the table in Access directly, NULL is accepted! Working with the data via UCanAccess
later leads to problems as the table cannot be written to:

> WARNING:Detected Not Null constraint breach, table Test, record
> Row[87:1][{id=2,value=}]: making the table Test  readonly

Opening and saving the table from the design view in Access solves the problem, but is not an option on the long run.
How to make Access respect the NOT-NULL constraint?

Comment: I am able to reproduce your issue. I will escalate it and report back here with any updates. It might be a difficult one to solve since Jackcess does set the appropriate "Required" column property, but there may be some other magic happening when Access saves the table definition (and actually *enforces* the NOT NULL constraint.)

Comment: This issue is also being discussed in the Jackcess help forum [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/discussion/456474/thread/7b20a0fd/#9e97).

Answer (score 2):

This has been traced to a [known issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/bugs/145/) with Jackcess 2.1.10. It should be fixed in upcoming releases of Jackcess and UCanAccess, respectively.